# How to create a model whose ID is the other model's foreign key

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm new to loopback and as far as I understood from documentations, you can't edit the built-in *User* model. So to extend that with address and other profile details, I've created a *Profile* model (based on *PersistedModel*).

Now I want the `id` of this model be equal to the `foreignKey` of *User*, so when I have the instance of *User*, I can get the profile simply by `id`.
This way I don't need to *find* the *Profile* instance by querying something like `email`. hence I don't need to have `email` in both models.

My question is:
How can I create the *Profile* model, and create a relation from *User* to *Profile*'s `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the user model and add as many properties you wish:

```js
{
  "name": "Profile",
  "plural": "profiles",
  "base": "User",
  ...
}
```

Comment: The problem I had with this was that I needed to edit the login method too, but either it didn't allow me or I couldn't find out how.

Comment: This is another topic, anyway I was perfectly able to override the login method in a couple of projects, just read the Loopback documentation to understand how to do it.

Comment: Do not override User model methods, do use remote hooks instead: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did eventually.